# Сломалось sudo /run/sudo/ts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

собственно, команды работают, но каждый раз запрашивается пароль, что очень неудобно. Можно ли это как-то исправить?(картинка ниже)

[image]

Comment: это один из плюсов Linux - базопасность

Comment: дык sudo же прямым !русским! текстом пишет в чём проблема...

Comment: Вопрос, как её исправить, с /etc/sudoers всё понятно.

Comment: @thematdev, `chown 0 /run/sudo/ts`... или удалением файла... или перезагрузкой...

Comment: @thematdev, ЗЫ: я бы больше беспокоился о том, что её вызвало... почти наверняка это твои действия и они могли быть разной степени разрушительности... но если других проблем нет, то скорей всего всё в порядке...

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chown 0 /run/sudo/ts
```

> ... или удалением файла... или перезагрузкой...